# Почему значение переменной равно пустой строке, а не undefined?

Tags: javascript, this

Есть такой код:

```
var user = {
  name: 'John',
  speak: function() {
    var sayHi = function() {
      console.log('Hi, my name is', this.name);
    }
    sayHi();
  }
}
user.speak(); // выведет 'Hi, my name is'
```

Почему в переменной name, которая создастся в глобальной области, будет значение пустой строки, а не undefined?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/GrqG0M6IQjpPO2 - почему это пустая строка? 
http://joxi.ru/823vDOeUJkZ1am - все правильно выводит. Вы без строки в консоль попробуйте вывести this.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае `this.name` === `window.name`. В свою очереде `window.name` это имя свойство окна, в котором хранится его текущее имя, и оно определенно по умолчанию. Более подробно можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

P.S. Если в любом месте скрита сделать `console.log(name)`, `undefined` также не вернется, если его явно не присвоить.